# Split dataset by means of levels in a factor

Tags: r, split

I want to split my dataset into 2 subset datasets. I am analysing behaviours and percentage of time spent exhibiting behaviours. I want to split it into behaviours that take up a mean time of less than 25% of the time, and another that contains the rest.

I am currently using
`ZB<- split(ZBehaviour, cut(ZBehaviour$Percentage.of.time, c(0, 25, 100), include.lowest=TRUE))`

Unfortunately, because I have multiple observations it splits the data as wanted but I find behaviours that (on mean) take up greater than 25% of time in the less than 25% dataset due to specific observations containing small instances of this behaviour.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Example of my data, the issue i find is that i find the grzing behaviour in both databases, when the mean should place it in the dabase containing behaviours that equate to over 25% of the mean percentage of time

Behaviour|Percentage|Observation

Grazing| 78.5|1

Sleeping|12.5|1

Walking|10|1

Grazing|12.3|2

Walking|20.7|2

Sleeping|24|2

etc

Comment: I suggest you look at the phrasing of question. The meaning of `"+25%"` and `"-25%"` is not clear to this native speaker of English. It might be helpful to show the code that was used for calculation of "Percentage.of.time"

Comment: It would also be really helpful if you could provide a small example of your data so that we could help you figure out an answer to your problem.